# error in installing pspell in windows

Tags: php, windows-installer, aspell, pspell

I have installed php using http://aspell.net/win32/ link. But I am getting the following error. Can anyone please help me out.

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pspell.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the php_pspell.dll file exists in that path.

Also, if you don't really need pspell - go to php.ini and comment it out. After that restart your xampp.

Comment: But I want pspell for my search engine. Can you give a better suggestion.

Comment: Check the path to the ext folder in php.ini file. Also, check that the slashes are like that "/" and not like that "\".

Comment: Alternatively, download a newer version of xampp. And don't modify anything in there - it should work out of the box.